# Problem retrieving dictionary from Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

During the first run, I am storing a `dictionary<string,dictionary<string,string>>` (lets call it `CategoryDictionary`).  When I re-run the code (without closing the emulator), the count in the `categorydictionary` becomes null.

Whatever I am getting from the `categorydictionary` are suppose to be displayed on the UI, so because of this problem am getting data on the UI only in the first run but 2nd run results in blank screen

```
while (enum1.MoveNext())
{
    KeyValuePair<string, string> keyvalue = (KeyValuePair<string, string>)enum1.Current;
    string key = keyvalue.Key;
    WidgetBean bean = null;
    dict.TryGetValue(key, out bean);
    ret.Add(key, bean);
}
```

So basically in the 2nd run bean has null values for all entries.

Comment: How are you storing the dictionary, and where does "enum1" come from?

Comment: Am chking the dictionary for the path="/" if its found then that is added to a temporary dictionary, enum1 is the enumerator for temp dict enties

Comment: Category_Dict.TryGetValue(CategoryPath, out temp); categorypath is assigned to "/"

Comment: Dictionary instances are not serializables. Use another type (you may define your own) that will be serialized/deserialized.

Comment: Am very much new to WP7 i dont know the concept of serialization. i did some reading after reading ur comment but no help.

Comment: U r so right i used using System.Runtime.Serialization;
[DataContact]
public class classname()
{
[datamember]
public int propertyname;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    [DataContact]
    public class classname()
    {
     [datamember]
     public int propertyname;
     }
```

i did this and the code is working fine now..